# Application box in Facebook timeline?

Tags: facebook, facebook-timeline

I created a Facebook application which occasionally publishes information to the timeline. As I was developing it, I noticed that at some point a box with the title of my application appeared in the timeline (a box similar to the "Friends" or "Activity" boxes). It contained an overview of the last posts published by my application.

Today, I noticed that this box is now gone from the timeline.

Does anybody know how are these boxes created? Is it something that Facebook do automatically? Is it possible to manually (or programmatically) put it back?

Any information on this would be great.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Application box will appear in user's timeline as long as you used [Add To Timeline](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/plugins/add-to-timeline/) social plugin or requested `publish_actions` permission from user and published an OpenGraph action.

Comment: I did request "publish_actions" and published several actions, but the box is still not back. Can Facebook automatically remove the box under certain conditions? In particular, I have published many actions but also removed many - I wonder if Facebook somehow considers that I'm not interested in this app and automatically removed the box? (I seem to remember having read something like that somewhere but can't find it anymore)

Answer (score 0):

As long as you have defined aggregations, the box will some and go depends on Facebook's algorithms. Usually, activity us grouped in the `Activity (Recent)` box on the user's timeline. But sometimes one of the aggregation boxes appear in the timeline too - unfortunately, there is no way to force it to appear all the time.

[image: Aggregations]